# Google maps v2 shows blank map on start ( randomly )

Tags: android, google-maps-api-2

I'm trying to use google map v2 in my application, I have successfully received debug.keystore's  SHA1 and received an api key from google console, also I have enabled google maps android v2 in services of google developers console.

My problem is this:
When I fully uninstall my app and install it in debug mode again, the map shows blank (no matter how many times I run my app), and then after a while (maybe 30mins or so) map appears and then it works just fine!

I must say that I have tried installing it with release.keystore with signed apk and the result was as equal as debugging mode.

I am also sure that I have a working internet connection and added permissions as the document said.

I am pretty sure that my api key is correct because the map loads sometimes!

My manifest is like this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>

<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="com.meehrdad.beetalk"
    android:versionCode="13"
    android:versionName="3.0" >

    <uses-sdk
        android:minSdkVersion="8"
        android:targetSdkVersion="16" />
    <permission android:name="com.meehrdad.beetalk.permission.MAPS_RECEIVE" android:protectionLevel="signature"/>
    <uses-permission android:name="com.meehrdad.beetalk.permission.MAPS_RECEIVE"/>

    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION"/>
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION"/>
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_WIFI_STATE"/>
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE"/>
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET"/>
    <uses-permission android:name="com.google.android.providers.gsf.permission.READ_GSERVICES"/>

    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE"/>

    <uses-feature android:glEsVersion="0x00020000" android:required="true"/>
<application android:allowBackup="false" android:icon="@drawable/beetalklogoicon" android:label="@string/app_name" android:theme="@style/AppTheme">
        <activity android:name="com.meehrdad.beetalk.MainActivity" android:label="@string/app_name">

        </activity>
        <activity android:name="com.meehrdad.beetalk.Userinfo" android:theme="@android:style/Theme.Dialog" android:label="اطلاعات کاربری"></activity>
        <activity android:name="com.meehrdad.beetalk.settingss" android:theme="@android:style/Theme.Dialog" android:label="تنظیمات"></activity>
        <activity android:name="com.meehrdad.beetalk.Notrooted" android:label="خطا" android:theme="@android:style/Theme.Dialog"></activity>
        <activity android:name="com.meehrdad.beetalk.About" android:theme="@android:style/Theme.Dialog"></activity>
        <activity android:name="com.meehrdad.beetalk.firsttime" android:label="متشکریم!" android:theme="@android:style/Theme.Dialog"></activity>
        <activity android:name="com.meehrdad.beetalk.Splash" android:label="@string/app_name" android:launchMode="singleInstance">


            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>

        </activity>
        <activity android:name="com.meehrdad.beetalk.SearchUser" android:theme="@android:style/Theme.Dialog" android:label="جستجوی کاربر"></activity>
        <activity android:name="com.meehrdad.beetalk.installbeetalk" android:label="@string/app_name" android:theme="@android:style/Theme.Dialog"></activity>
        <activity android:name="com.meehrdad.beetalk.itsnotrooted"></activity>

    <activity android:name="com.meehrdad.beetalk.old"></activity>
    <activity android:name="com.meehrdad.beetalk.installgoogleplayservices" android:label="google play services را نصب کنید" android:theme="@android:style/Theme.Dialog"></activity>

    <meta-data android:name = "com.google.android.gms.version" android:value="@integer/google_play_services_version" />
    <meta-data android:name="com.google.android.maps.v2.API_KEY" android:value="my api key" />

    </application>

</manifest>
```

EDIT:

My Logcat Messages:

```
01-17 17:01:41.229: D/dalvikvm(6112): GC_FOR_ALLOC freed 64K, 4% free 6451K/6659K, paused 46ms
01-17 17:01:41.229: I/dalvikvm-heap(6112): Grow heap (frag case) to 7.341MB for 1048592-byte allocation
01-17 17:01:41.269: D/dalvikvm(6112): GC_CONCURRENT freed 1K, 4% free 7474K/7751K, paused 1ms+2ms
01-17 17:01:41.309: D/dalvikvm(6112): GC_FOR_ALLOC freed 0K, 4% free 7474K/7751K, paused 20ms
01-17 17:01:41.409: I/dalvikvm-heap(6112): Grow heap (frag case) to 7.784MB for 465140-byte allocation
01-17 17:01:41.439: D/dalvikvm(6112): GC_CONCURRENT freed 0K, 5% free 7928K/8263K, paused 1ms+1ms
01-17 17:01:41.459: D/TextLayoutCache(6112): Using debug level: 0 - Debug Enabled: 0
01-17 17:01:41.479: D/libEGL(6112): loaded /system/lib/egl/libGLES_android.so
01-17 17:01:41.479: D/libEGL(6112): loaded /system/lib/egl/libEGL_adreno200.so
01-17 17:01:41.489: D/libEGL(6112): loaded /system/lib/egl/libGLESv1_CM_adreno200.so
01-17 17:01:41.489: D/libEGL(6112): loaded /system/lib/egl/libGLESv2_adreno200.so
01-17 17:01:41.659: D/OpenGLRenderer(6112): Enabling debug mode 0
01-17 17:01:46.309: I/dalvikvm(6112): Could not find method android.app.Notification$Builder.setPriority, referenced from method com.google.android.gms.common.GooglePlayServicesUtil.a
01-17 17:01:46.309: W/dalvikvm(6112): VFY: unable to resolve virtual method 192: Landroid/app/Notification$Builder;.setPriority (I)Landroid/app/Notification$Builder;
01-17 17:01:46.309: D/dalvikvm(6112): VFY: replacing opcode 0x6e at 0x0035
01-17 17:01:46.339: D/dalvikvm(6112): DexOpt: unable to opt direct call 0x00a9 at 0x3f in Lcom/google/android/gms/common/GooglePlayServicesUtil;.a
01-17 17:01:46.409: D/dalvikvm(6112): GC_CONCURRENT freed 1354K, 17% free 7121K/8519K, paused 1ms+2ms
01-17 17:01:46.509: I/x(6112): Making Creator dynamically
01-17 17:01:46.999: D/dalvikvm(6112): GC_CONCURRENT freed 172K, 13% free 7433K/8519K, paused 2ms+3ms
01-17 17:01:47.159: I/Google Maps Android API(6112): Google Play services client version: 6587000
01-17 17:01:47.189: I/Google Maps Android API(6112): Google Play services package version: 6599038
01-17 17:01:47.249: D/dalvikvm(6112): GC_CONCURRENT freed 167K, 10% free 7689K/8519K, paused 4ms+2ms
01-17 17:01:47.389: D/dalvikvm(6112): GC_CONCURRENT freed 182K, 6% free 8019K/8519K, paused 2ms+3ms
01-17 17:01:47.509: D/dalvikvm(6112): GC_CONCURRENT freed 304K, 5% free 8287K/8647K, paused 1ms+3ms
01-17 17:01:47.549: D/dalvikvm(6112): GC_FOR_ALLOC freed 112K, 5% free 8407K/8839K, paused 24ms
01-17 17:01:47.569: D/dalvikvm(6112): GC_FOR_ALLOC freed 126K, 7% free 8535K/9095K, paused 24ms
01-17 17:01:47.609: D/dalvikvm(6112): GC_FOR_ALLOC freed 373K, 7% free 8603K/9223K, paused 25ms
01-17 17:01:47.639: D/dalvikvm(6112): GC_FOR_ALLOC freed 126K, 6% free 8730K/9223K, paused 25ms
01-17 17:01:47.669: D/dalvikvm(6112): GC_FOR_ALLOC freed 369K, 8% free 8797K/9479K, paused 24ms
01-17 17:01:47.699: D/dalvikvm(6112): GC_FOR_ALLOC freed 126K, 6% free 8925K/9479K, paused 25ms
01-17 17:01:47.889: D/dalvikvm(6112): GC_CONCURRENT freed 402K, 5% free 9418K/9863K, paused 2ms+3ms
01-17 17:01:48.109: D/dalvikvm(6112): GC_CONCURRENT freed 220K, 3% free 10193K/10503K, paused 2ms+3ms
01-17 17:01:48.349: D/dalvikvm(6112): GC_CONCURRENT freed 661K, 7% free 10822K/11527K, paused 2ms+4ms
01-17 17:01:48.989: D/dalvikvm(6112): GC_CONCURRENT freed 1425K, 13% free 10863K/12359K, paused 2ms+2ms
01-17 17:01:49.809: D/dalvikvm(6112): GC_CONCURRENT freed 913K, 8% free 11432K/12423K, paused 2ms+6ms
01-17 17:01:50.139: D/OpenGLRenderer(6112): Flushing caches (mode 0)
01-17 17:01:50.859: D/dalvikvm(6112): GC_FOR_ALLOC freed 1306K, 13% free 11496K/13191K, paused 206ms
```

Comment: Do you get any messages in your logcat?

Comment: i receive some messages , it's not errors but i think Google Client takes too much time to verify Api key . i will post these messages

Comment: @user3249477 i have posted my logcat

Comment: Any solutions here? Can you interact with the app when its not showing the map?

Comment: Yes app is working just fine and the only problem is google map . regarding my previews comment , sometimes verifying api key takes too long . i haven't found a solution yet.